# Deusovi - trapped!

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

> I have been trapped in a void I know nothing of. There is nothing but four plain red walls, annoying me very much. Thanks to my experience in Puzzling Stack Exchange, I am observant to find a small switch at the corner of a wall. Curious and seeing it as the only possible way out, I pressed it. 
>  Screens appeared on each of the four walls. Below are pictures of them. A keyboard lay before me on the ground, here it is:

Walls:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Keyboard:

[image]

---

HINTS

*helpfulness level 1:*

> read the last wall

*helpfulness level 2:*

> .

*helpfulness level 4:*

> The ... that the name (7-letter word) refers to is mainly green in colour, on the surface

*helpfulness level 5:*

> Have you ... that ... on the wordsearch?

---

Note/ Hint:
@Deusovi, it has been four days... I can't believe you can't solve this on the spot!

Comment: Vf PBAFRPGHE n zvfgnxr sbe PBAFRPGRGHE? (qvntbanyyl sebz gur gbc-yrsg pbeare)

Comment: Gurer ner gjb RBF (gurl funer gur fnzr B), ohg bar bs gurz vf nyernql pbzcyrgryl pbirerq ol bgure jbeqf fb V'z nffhzvat gur bgure. Fnzr guvat jvgu FRQ. Gura 4 yrggref erznva va gur raq: SLXV. Jung gb qb jvgu gung vf n zlfgrel.

Comment: Why is it always Deusovi? Poor sod ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor for some reason that is irrelevant to this puzzle but will be disclosed in due course ;)

Comment: What a mixed-up devious plot. Also, nice hint. At first I thought it was pointless, but it appears I was mistaken.

Comment: @Brandon_J Do you mean rot13(vg vf abg cbvagyrff? arne...)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton but it is a "point" :)

Comment: Based on hints 1 & 2, the last wall gives me an eight letter word, not a seven letter one. Does that mean I'm off base, or does it just mean there's more steps to it?

Comment: Welp, it doesn't feel even enough to warrant a partial answer, so I'll just post it here for anyone who wants to pick it up and potentially run with it. I notice that hints 1 & 2 seem to nudge towards: rot13(gur jbeq "RYYVCFVF", fvapr gung vf yvgrenyyl gur "anzr bs n(a) ..."). What to do with that, I'm not sure (especially since it's 8 letters not 7), though rot13(vs gur svefg jnyy nyfb nccyvrf urer, lbh pbhyq erzbir gur qhcyvpngr yrggref naq erqhpr vg gb whfg "RC" naq cbffvoyl pbzovar vg jvgu Neanhq'f "RIV" + "VSL" fbzrubj).

Comment: Regarding hint 3, perhaps ROT13(gur "uvqqra" guvat vf pyhvat gur yrggref va gur zvqqyr bs gur gvgyr, tvivat hf IVGE, juvpu pbzovarq jvgu gur yrggref sebz gur jbeq frnepu tvirf IVGEVSL?) Doesn't really account for hint 2 or the rest of the text on the last wall though

Comment: @Alconja nice approach! You are near, but the answer is a bit simpler

Comment: @PiIsNot3 nope...

Comment: @Brandon_J In fact... you are **very** near...

Comment: @OmegaKrypton If someone isn't already in a comment thread and is not the creator of the post (and has not edited it), you cannot $@$ping them so they won't know you referenced them unless they just happen to read that comment.  In general, if you don't get their name as an auto-completion when you type the @ and the start of their name, you can't ping them.  (In general because if all they've done is edit the post they won't auto-complete even though they are pingable in that case)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Final update**

The answer is

> SPOTIFY

thanks to @Deusovi himself in the comments. It did cross my mind, but I didn't find a convincing explanation, especially one that would fit the hints:

> The green thing? The sequence $a(n)$? The fact that we're looking for a verb (well, spotify can be sometimes used as a verb like many similar neologisms, but the puzzle didn't feature music - or perhaps I just didn't find it)? One hint that was removed now: "something good hidden in the puzzle, have you *found* it?" - it seemed to refer to the word *mercy* (unless this would make it too obvious a hint)? There are most likely a lot of references that I don't have here.

**Update:**

I think the answer is

> TESTIFY

Explanation:

> Now a letter was removed from the grid, only FIY remain in the crossword. Also it was given in the comments that the `duos` clue is in fact irrelevant. I believe that the clue `(name of a(n) ...)` indicates that the 7-letter answer is made of two parts: the name of a sequence (a(n)), and three letters suggested by the three dots. The three letters are IFY. The sequence is the Lorem Ipsum which is a common **test** filler to test page layout.

**Previous partial answer:**

> Below is what remains after all words from the Lorem Ipsum are crossed out.
>
>  I first thought that
>  "The duos, disdain" meant that we are supposed to ignore two-letter words, but it turns out that this would change nothing to the result (the four letters that remain aren't part of such words). So, another option is that we are supposed to remove the letters DUOS from DEUSOVI. This leaves us with EVI.
>
>  Now, together, EVI and IKYF make 7 letters, which is the expected amount of letters in the answer. Yet they don't seem to combine well into a verb (*what to do*).
>
>  [image]

Ideas that don't work:

> 1. Relate the three dots from the last wall to the three dots from the keyboard and interpret the sequence $a(n)$ as the sequence of function keys.
>
>  2. Interpret the dots as a hint to "acronyms" and the letters FYI as such.
>
>  3. Reverse all relevant letters (such as FYI) as suggested by the mirror under the keyboard.
>
>  4. Look for a sequence of numbers with a particular name hidden in there (Like Fibonacci, etc.).

Comment: oops, sorry on consectur and the crossword... i made this manually... updated

Comment: something is wrong with your seven letters... no hints for now tho ;) keep it up :)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton well sure because you've removed one of them :)

Comment: Well actually your initial thought on the duos quote was right, so if what u mentioned is the case you may as well ignore it... ;)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Oh right. Well that's helpful.

Comment: nice try... but firstly, lipsum is a te**x**t filler, not a test filler. your approach was near, so keep the hard work up! (ps: the answer is not the current one)

Comment: hi there, new hint added... :)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I added a couple of ideas that don't seem to lead anywhere. Are you suggesting to ROT13( pbhag gur npghny cvkryf va gur ynfg jnyy (r.t. 62 69 69 66 sbe gur jbeq Jung)? )

Comment: nope, you're drifting further away...

Comment: see if the new hint helps?

Comment: After [a conversation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50255560#50255560) I've found that the answer is "SPOTIFY". (I don't see how we were supposed to get this either.) I'm mentioning it here instead of posting it as an answer so you can edit it in, since you did the actual work for this puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi it did cross my mind, among other things, yet I couldn' t see the reason. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Why was this about Deusovi specifically? And the answer feels particularly unmotivated. Was the idea that rot13(lbh'er fhccbfrq gb *fcbg* gur *V S L* va gur jbeqfrnepu, naq guhf gur ynfg jnyy'f svyy-va-gur-oynax vf  FCBG VSL)? That seems like something that'd only occur to you to use IF you'd already realized rot13(gung trggvat gur VSL jnfa'g whfg N fgrc lbh unq gb qb, vg jnf GUR fgrc lbh unq gb qb). From other comments it seems it isn't all that obvious to anyone else how to get to this end.... something to consider for future puzzles. (Remember, your solver isn't in your head!)